Setting Random Background Images for Main Activity (Android Studio - Java)
Heyo!
So, I've been having issues setting a random background image to my main activity, the general idea is when the app is opening, it will run the random generator, pick a number, and assign an image accordingly. Currently with my code, when I try to run it, the background doesn't change. Any help would be appreciated!
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Random random = new Random();
        int[] mainImages = new int[]{R.drawable.mountain, R.drawable.door, R.drawable.stairs_edit, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.image2};
        int rndBackground = random.nextInt(5);
        MainActivity.this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(mainImages[rndBackground]);
}

I've tried setting the image with .setBackgroundDrawable(getResource().getDrawable()) approaches, along with just trying to set an individual image without much luck. Results usually result in no background change or the app crashing.

Instead of setting the background to the window, have you tried to set the background of the root element of activity_main layout?

@rand Yeah, I tried using View view = findViewById(R.id.CLmain).getRootView();         view.setBackgroundResource(mainImages[rndBackground]); But no image change.

It would be nice to see a stack trace of the crash?

@PineapplePie Sorry, the current code is actually not crashing, I misspoke in original post.

If R.id.CLmain is a ConstraintLayout try this: ConstraintLayout view = findViewById(R.id.CLMain); view.setBackgroundResource(mainImages[rndBackground]);. You don't need to call getRootView()

Go to the XML layout of the Main Activity. Assign an ID to the root ViewGroup. For example, if the root ViewGroup is LinearLayout, you can assign an ID to it by adding android:id="@+id/rootView"
It should look something like this:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Now get a reference of it in your JAVA code:
// Root View which is a linearLayout
LinearLayout rootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find root view using it's ID
    rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    Random random = new Random();
    int[] mainImages = new int[]{R.drawable.mountain, R.drawable.door, R.drawable.stairs_edit, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.image2};
    int rndBackground = random.nextInt(5);

    // Set root view's background resource
    rootView.setBackgroundResource(mainImages[rndBackground]);
}

Hope it helps.
